# Difference between GMT, GMT+0, GMT-0, GMT0 on Unix

Tags: unix, time

Under `/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo`

I can see the following 4 different types of info for `GMT`

```
GMT
GMT+0
GMT-0
GMT0
```

Are there any differences between these 4 types of `GMT` zone times? If so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they are all the same, or at least have the same values.

Yoo can see all here: [TimeZones](http://www.gsp.com/support/virtual/admin/unix/tz/gmt/)

Answer (score 5):

On my system (and likely yours as well), `GMT`, `GMT+0` and `GMT0` are all symlinked to `GMT-0`. So there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Hasturkun's answer - on systems based on glibc, `GTM`, `GMT+0` etc will be always symlinked, because that's how it's defined in `glibc/timezone/backward` mapping file. Specifically:

```
Link    Etc/GMT                 GMT+0
Link    Etc/GMT                 GMT-0
Link    Etc/GMT                 GMT0
Link    Etc/GMT                 Greenwich
```